# Is there an auto file creation feature/plugin in Netbeans which works in conjunction with 'Select In Projects'

Tags: netbeans, code-completion

Consider the following arbitrary line of code:

```
$object = new My_Object();
```

In Netbeans you are able to right click on 'My_Object' and select the 'Select in Projects' option from the menu that appears. This will open the class file for the 'My_Object' class in the editor for you (provided that you have your paths set up correctly)

My question is:  Is there a feature or plugin for Netbeans that would create the My_Object class file automatically if it does not already exist? (or at least prompt you if you want to create it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already exists. When you instanciate an new object that has not been defined, put your cursor on this line. Then on the left bar (where line numbers are) you'll see a light bulb, click on it on choose

> Create class "My_Object" in ...

Comment: This was very helpful thanks!  I work with Zend Framework and found Zend_Tool to provide even more useful functionality.  A useful tutorial to set up Zend_Tool with Netbeans is here: http://www.kilinjal.com/blog/how-configure-zend-tool-netbeans